# TypeScript Union of two Interfaces with one being optional

Tags: typescript

I would like to define a type as a union of two interfaces. One of the two interfaces should be optional, meaning that the union type should either have *all or none* of the properties of the optional interface. It should now be allowed for the union type to include only a subset of the properties of the optional interface.

I.e. something like this:

```js
interface A {
  a1: string
  a2: string
}

interface B {
  b1: string
  b2: string
}

type C = A | (A & B)
```

However, this doesn't *quite* work like I would expect.

1. Partial inclusion of interface A properties is prohibited, e.g.

```js
const c: C = {
  // a1: 'a1',
  a2: 'a2',
  b1: 'b1',
  b2: 'b2',
}
```

results in this error, as expected: "Property 'a1' is missing in type '{ a2: string; b1: string; b2: string; }'"

2. BUT, partial inclusion of interface B properties is allowed, e.g.

```js
const c: C = {
  a1: 'a1',
  a2: 'a2',
  // b1: 'b1',
  b2: 'b2',
}
```

does not result in an error.

**What am I missing? How can I "fix" my types to achieve what I want?**

---

Other alternatives I have tried

```js
type C = A & (B | {}) // Same as above.

type C = A & (B | undefined) // This catches { a1: 'a1', a2: 'a2', b2: 'b2' }, but doesn't allow for { a1: 'a1', a2: 'a2' }, i.e. it requires the union to have all of the interface B properties always.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object types in TypeScript are *extendible* and not "exact" (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  So the value `{ a1: 'a1', a2: 'a2', b2: 'b2'}` is a perfectly valid value of type `A | (A & B)`, since it is assignable to `A`.  Normally you'd get [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#excess-property-checks) to warn you about `b2`, but since `b2` is part of `A & B`, the compiler won't see that as an excess property.

One idea would be to use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to say "something with none of the properties of T", like this:

```
type NoneOf<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: never };
```

[Optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) are as close as we can get to prohibiting properties. They're optional, so you can leave them out (or make them `undefined`, depending on compiler options)... but if you don't leave them out they need to be `never` and you won't find a value of that type.

So then `NoneOf<B>` would be `{b1?: never, b2?: never}`.  Then the type you're looking for would be

```
type C = A & (B | NoneOf<B>)
```

And you can verify that it works:

```
let c: C;
c = { a1: 'a1', a2: 'a2' }; // okay
c = { a1: 'a1', a2: 'a2', b1: 'b1', b2: 'b2' }; // okay
c = { a1: 'a1', a2: 'a2', b2: 'b2' } // error!
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLgRgC5kBnMKUAcxzwCZiyKRqBfLLUSWRFAIUxoAjIqXJUh9UU1bt2YAJ4AHFADkA9iAgB5GAB4AKgD5kAXkzIA2gGlkoZAGsI8tTGT6AugH5imgG7RkFgBuOSUUAGFTNGQAMmQACn4AH2R1TR1dXkMASnYAGwgwZARicJCEKIw8EQByAhqAGjpiOtoawKDkAHou5DV7OHksCrMqghb6prhJVsbkYRbhOcEZlfbg7t7+weHK6on8OemJtqaVxbbAzeRoKDUoAEJ2IA)

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
interface A {
  a1: string;
  a2: string;
}

interface B {
  b1: string;
  b2: string;
}

type C = (A & Partial<B>) | (B & Partial<A>);
```

Either `A` or `B`s keys must be there entirely. The other one doesn't matter.

```
const valid: C = {
  a1: "a1",
  // a2: "a2",
  b1: "b1",
  b2: "b2"
};

const valid2: C = {
  a1: "a1",
  a2: "a2",
  b1: "b1"
  // b2: "b2"
};

const invalid: C = {
  a1: "a1",
  // a2: "a2",
  b1: "b1"
  // b2: "b2"
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLgRgC5kBnMKUAcwG4c8AmYsikGrAXyy1ElkRQBCmOgCMipclVq4RjCSzacsYAJ4AHFAGFkAXmQAKdADJkABThQwwOABsAPAIB8ASmQAfA0JPnL1%206hdaLAQAexAyZAA3W2AAE2JtPWxcAHoUvHEAIgJMgBo6NIZibPo80SyxMpk5TNlMjiDQ8LAomNi5ROFcAmKc-O6auFL%205DFiyoL02XHShq4miNBomziE3S6M3vwq5EKh3uHy8e3J0Zq6hqA)

Comment: What I'm looking for is `A`s keys must be there entirely and `B`s keys must be there entirely or not at all. So both your "valid" examples should actually be invalid. The only two valid cases should be `valid1= { a1: 'a1', a2: 'a2' }` or `valid2 = { a1: 'a1', a2: 'a2', b1: 'b1', b2: 'b2' }`.